# Collection Cross References not Abbreviating

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

According to the [citation style](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/sites/default/files/style-sheet_0.pdf) I follow, multiple children of the same collection should have their parent cited as a separate entry, and the details of the parent abbreviated in each child's citation (with a cross reference to the full separate entry). However, biblatex does not produce this behaviour for me, and instead cites the full details in *both* the parent *and* child entries. The problem is the lack of abbreviation in the child entries.

Here is my MWE (it's technically not fully minimal in the biblatex call, but I thought it best to include the other parameters I'm using, though they don't seem to be relevant):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified,citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp,uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibMaster.bib}

\begin{document}

Cite \textcite{Finlay2012}, but see \textcite{Fulk2012}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:

[image: References done incorrectly]

I can get the right results *in this respect* by using biblatex-chicago instead, and calling:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Which gives:

[image: References done correctly]

But I'd really prefer to do this using bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified, which otherwise produces exactly what I want for how citations are laid out in detail.

I hope there's an obvious parameter or something that I've missed in the biblatex description. Something like biblatex-chicago's (default) longcrossref=false option.

Edited to add: Here are the bibliography entries cited in the example:

```
@incollection{Finlay2012,
author = "Alison Finlay",
title = "{Glúmr Geirason,} \textit{Gráfeldardrápa}",
crossref = "Whaley2012",
pages = "245-266",
}

@incollection{Fulk2012,
author = "R. D. Fulk",
title = "{Sigvatr Þórðarson,} \textit{Austrfararvísur}",
pages = "578-614",
crossref = "Whaley2012",
}

@collection{Whaley2012,
editor = "Diana Whaley",
title = "Poetry from the {Kings' Sagas} 1",
subtitle = "From mythical times to c. 1035",
series = "Skaldic Poetry of the Scandinavian Middle Ages 1",
date = "2012",
publisher = "Brepols",
address = "Tournout",
}
```

Comment: The styles `biblatex-sp-unified` and `sp-authoryear-comp` cannot be found on my system and a quick web search did not turn up anything officially looking. Where can we get those styles? (Are you using a very old TeX system? Did you install the styles manually?) It would also help if you could share the relevant entries from your `.bib` file as copy-and-pasteable text in the question.

Comment: I got biblatex-sp-unified from here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-unified

I suspect that I got sp-authoryear-comp via this page, though the relevant link there is now broken: https://info.semprag.org/install

I'm using MiKTeX 4.8.

I'll edit the .bib entries in right now -- I had meant to do that in the first place, but forgot in the end.

Comment: Also, I should say that running it with just \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} produces the same problem of not abbreviating the entries. I included the fuller parameters in case these were relevant to a solution, but they don't seem to be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: The style available from the CTAN link at the moment (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-unified) is called just `unified` and not `biblatex-sp-unified`. Could you possibly update to the current version so that we're all on the same page? It is pretty difficult to help if we can't get hold of the style you are using.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are after, then this is a behaviour controlled by the style. The standard `biblatex` styles do not happen to abbreviate the reference in this case, but this is largely irrelevant if you are talking about a customised style anyway. (If you were using standard styles, you could easily switch to one of the `biblatex-ext` styles which provide the `citexref` option that should do something that comes close-ish to what you want. But this isn't an option with a third-party style like `unified`.)

Comment: In that case, I may need to simply adjust my citation style wholesale. I have begun to look into this, and I think I can get fairly close to the linguistics USS.

Comment: If you can post code based on a "unified" style that works with an up-to-date TeX distribution I can have a look at what needs to be done. But if you need to deviate to a larger degree from what the style gives you at the moment, it might indeed be better to start off from one of the standard styles.